# Extracting literal html text from within an XML element in iOS

Tags: ios, xml

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<ContentItem>
<DataContent><strong>A heading</strong><br /> eSome detailed text</DataContent>
</ContentItem>

<ContentItem>
<DataContent><strong>Another heading</strong><br /> Some other detailed text</DataContent>
</ContentItem>
```

I need to extract the literal strings of HTML between the `DataContent` elements, and then join them together into a single html document later on.

I recognize that the HTML I want will get parsed into various XML elements itself, so I guess what I'm looking for is a way to find the text representation of an XML element and all its child elements.

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot use NSXMLParser?

Comment: Well, NSXMLParser interprets the html as additional XML elements rather than giving me the characters, so I have to keep track of the elements that have passed, reformat them back to HTML tags, and append everything together again, it's quite unwieldy. At least that's how I've encountered it so far I'm not sure if there is another way I can be doing it.

Comment: If its your XML maybe you could look into changing it and specifying the HTML using CDATA?  - then the NSXMLParser should theoretically treat it as character data and not markup.

Comment: That's what I'd like to do but it's not my XML it's provided by my customer, they are unable to change it.

Comment: Why don't you read it as a string and mange your own parsing?

Comment: @RileyE because writing my own parser for off-spec xml would have taken too long for what I needed to do.

Comment: @RileyE unless you had something else in mind?

Comment: Well, your goal seems very specific, so I figured that making a specific parser wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Right, I see, and reading my question it's clear I wrote it poorly. I didn't bring up the fact that these `ContentItem` nodes were deep within a fairly sizable document. So the trouble I had was that with `NSXMLParser`, I didn't see a way to just grab all the string content within a node as raw characters... basically inserting a CDATA on the fly. And then with the DOM parser I tried had basically the same problem - couldn't figure out how to get the raw characters associated with an element or rebuild such from what it had parsed. Then customers replaced w/ even worse format & I forgot this Q